# PHP: file_get_contents hangs on a specific URL

Tags: php, rss, simplexml, file-get-contents

So I have a simple php file that is supposed to read the source of an rss feed and write it to a SimpleXML object. My code works just fine with most url's. I've tested with CNN and a few others. However, the URL I actually need it to work with hangs. I've talked a bit with the company that hosts the content, and they say there's nothing special and it should work. Can anyone throw out any ideas as to why a particular URL would hang? (FYI the content comes from a blog hosted by Compendium)

Here's my code:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/rss?compendium_feed_count=3";
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
print_r($xml);
$xmldoc = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
print_r($xmldoc);
```

Comment: Can you even ping/wget the host/URL you're trying to hit?

Comment: there is so many factors, you have to share rss link. otherwise, we'll write every possibility.

Comment: Try doing it with cURL instead and using some of the options you have available such as following redirects. There is too many possibilities here to address this as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I was just looking to possibilities. I knew it could be a number of this. I figured out the problem actually. Now I just need to come up with a solution. The new question may be better posted to serverfault though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer it turns out is because the blog I'm trying to pull from shares the same domain name as the host it's coming from. The script I wrote sits on example.com and the blog sits at example.com/blog. They're separate servers, but apparently the server sees the url the script is trying to access and is looking internally instead of externally. If I put the script on a different host to test it works fine. So now I have to figure out how to make the server push this kind of request out.

Edit: So, the problem was that the webserver had a reverse proxy set up for the '/blog' path pointing to another server. I had to route the request through the proxy too. It was done like this:

```
$aContext = array('http'=>array('proxy'=>'tcp://client-proxy.exampleproxy.com:80','request_fulluri'=>true));
$url = "http://www.example.com/rss?compendium_feed_count=3";
$cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);
$xml = file_get_contents($url,FALSE,$cxContext);
$xmldoc = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
```